# How to create Shell script to Start Mac installed Application?

Tags: shell-script

Actually i'm new to Shell Script. So i want to know how to create shell script to run application on Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a broad questions with no specific information. So this answer will also be broad and there are many possible ways.

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Go to the folder where you want to locate your script (i.e. `cd /tmp`)
3. Create and edit a new file: `vi myscript.sh`
4. write your script. (Press "i" to edit the new file if you are new to vi)
5. After you are done press ESC to stop the edit mode in vi.
6. Enter `:wq` (it will show at the bottom of the screen and instructs to write and quit). Just use `:w` if you do not want to quit. Just use `:q` if you want to quit after saving. Use `:q!` if you want to quit without saving.
7. Make your file executable using `chmod a+x myscript.sh` (This makes it executable to ALL users. you can replace the a to make it executable to owner or group)
8. Now you can execute your shell script using `./myscript.sh`

Most significant part is step 7. You might want to use your favourite text editor for step 2-6.

To open a specific application, you can use `open` in your script. Example "myscript.sh":

```
open -a firefox
```

The `-a` option starts the application independent on its location.

Comment: Thank you sir!.. but i want exact shell script code for start the application like(Chrome or Outlook) that means if i run the shell script on Terminal outlook should open automatically.

Comment: added the "open" command for you. Sorry, picked a different brower as I don't have Chome,

Comment: Thank you so much sir its worked for me...